# How to get current position of 3D object while animation is going on in ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, scenekit, arkit

On image marker detection, I want to play animation of walking guy within that marker boundary only using `ARKit`. For that I want to find out the position of that 3D object while it is walking on marker. Animation is created using external 3D authoring tool and saved in `.scnassets` as `.dae` file.  I have added node and start animation using below code:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {  


     if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor {  
          DispatchQueue.main.async { 
              //let translation = imageAnchor.transform.columns.3     
                let idleScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/WalkAround/WalkAround.dae")!  

             // This node will be parent of all the animation models  
                let node1 = SCNNode()  

                // Add all the child nodes to the parent node  
                for child in idleScene.rootNode.childNodes {  
                     node1.addChildNode(child)  
                }  

               node1.scale = SCNVector3(0.2, 0.2, 0.2)  
               let physicalSize = imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize  
               let size = CGSize(width: 500, height: 500)  

               let skScene = SKScene(size: size)  
               skScene.backgroundColor = .white  

               let plane = SCNPlane(width: self.referenceImage!.physicalSize.width, height: self.referenceImage!.physicalSize.height)  

               let material = SCNMaterial()  
               material.lightingModel = SCNMaterial.LightingModel.constant  
               material.isDoubleSided = true  
               material.diffuse.contents = skScene  
               plane.materials = [material]  
               let rectNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)  
               rectNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2  

               node.addChildNode(rectNode)  
               node.addChildNode(node1)  

               self.loadAnimation(withKey: "walking", sceneName: "art.scnassets/WalkAround/SambaArmtr", animationIdentifier: "SambaArmtr-1")  
         }  
    }  
}  
func loadAnimation(withKey: String, sceneName:String, animationIdentifier:String) {  
    let sceneURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: sceneName, withExtension: "dae")  
    let sceneSource = SCNSceneSource(url: sceneURL!, options: nil)  

    if let animationObject = sceneSource?.entryWithIdentifier(animationIdentifier, withClass: CAAnimation.self) {  
        // The animation will only play once  
        animationObject.repeatCount = 1  
    }  
}
```

I tried using `node.presentation.position` in both below methods to get current position of object.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval)          
// Or
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)
```

If I will not move device anymore once animation has been started, those methods will not get called and till the time I am getting same position of node. Thats why I am not getting where I am wrong. Or is there any way to get current position of object while animation is going on in ARKit?

Comment: I don't really understand the issue, please rephrase the question. It seems unlikely that any of this works because the `node` variable is redeclared and never added to the scene.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to get the current frame within an embedded animation. With that said, the animation embedded within a model uses CoreAnimation to run the animation. You could use the `CAAimationDelegate` to listen to the start/end events of your animation and run a timer. The timer would give you the best estimate of which frame the animation is on.

References:
SceneKit Animating Content Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/animation/animating_scenekit_content

CAAnimationDelegate Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caanimationdelegate